# Creating mappings for command-line mode

Tags: command-line

I have made a few mappings for my personal configuration file, and I think I am getting a hang of it, however, I am wondering if there are any particular tricks to create mappings for command-line mode.

I know that there are keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for deleting the  character before the cursor or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> for moving one `WORD` left, and I know how to remap these, but I am unsure what my options are when I want to make new ones.  If I wanted a key (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>) which deletes the content of a parenthesis in insert mode, I would do this with:

```
imap <C-_> <C-O>dib
```

However, this relies on using normal mode, and I am unsure how, if possible, I could achieve something like that for command-line mode.

Comment: `inoremap` would be more appropriate for your mapping. See `:help recursive-mapping`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim provides a few mechanisms for inspecting the contents of the command-line (See *Further Reading*, below), but not many for directly manipulating it.

One way you could create the mapping you describe above would be to go via the command-line window:

```
:cnoremap <expr> <c-_> &cedit.'dib'.'<c-c>'
```

This creates an expression mapping that opens the command-line window, performs a normal mode `dib` and then returns to the regular command-line. The downside to this method is that it leaves the command-line window open after the mapping completes (although it no longer has focus). The window closes when you enter or cancel the command. See [Mass's comment, below](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/creating-mappings-for-command-line-mode/14134#comment24259_14134) for a clever fix.

Your only other real option for complex `cmap`s is to use <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> which allows you to replace the entire command-line with the result of an expression.

#### Further Reading

- `:help cmdwin`
- `:help 'cedit'`
- `:help c_CTRL-\_e`
- `:help c_CTRL-R_=`
- `:help getcmdline()`
- `:help getcmdtype()`
- `:help getcmdpos()`
- `:help setcmdpos()`

Comment: After `<c-c>` the command line window is only kind-of open; a redraw will hide it. You could force a redraw like so `cnoremap <expr> <c-_> &cedit.'dib'.'<c-c><c-r>=execute("redraw")<cr>'`

Comment: @Mass Yeah, I didn't think the distinction was important enough to include in the answer. It didn't occur to me you could use the expression register to execute a `:redraw`, though. Clever!

Comment: Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)

Comment: @Rich. Thanks for the answer and the pointers to where I can learn more about it.  I will try to make some new mappings to get used to the command line window.